# Simple button listener gone wrong

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, buttonclick, google-chrome-console

I haven't done any development in a long time and I'm looking to start from scratch on a project turning my raspberry pi into a Spotify remote. I have a pi 4 using the latest raspberry pi OS. I have installed apache and got to my webpage. I see my button displayed but can't seem to see any logs when I press the button. I don't know if it's my chrome settings or my code. Any insight?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spotify Web Playback SDK Quick Start</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Spotify Web Playback SDK Quick Start</h1>
    <button id="togglePlay">Toggle Play</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('togglePlay').addEventListener('click', console.log('togglePlay Pressed'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've changed chrome console settings to enable "Log XMLHttpRequests", "Show timestamps" and "Preserve log upon navigation" I am seeing the "togglePlay Pressed" in the log when the page loads up but not seeing the button presses in the chrome console when I actually press. I don't want the function to run just by loading the page either can someone help a beginner out?

```
content-scripts.js:1 INS: content-ads.js loaded:  http://192.168.1.80/
12:42:29.561 Navigated to http://192.168.1.80/
12:42:29.572 content-scripts.js:1 TSS: content-tss.js loaded:  http://192.168.1.80/
12:42:29.573 content-scripts.js:1 INS: content-blocked-items.js loaded:  http://192.168.1.80/
12:42:29.579 (index):10 togglePlay Pressed
12:42:29.581 content-scripts.js:1 CONTENT_SHELL: Page allowed. Skipping shell injection blocks
12:42:29.581 content-scripts.js:1 GET TAB ID RESPONSE:  {tabId: 558604399}
12:42:29.583 content-scripts.js:1 TSS: excluded result:  {excluded: true}
12:42:29.584 content-scripts.js:1 TSS: Excluding content tss (trigger: send-mesage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to write event listener -

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('togglePlay').addEventListener('click', () => {
       console.log('Your Message');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, can you help me understand why .addEventListener('click', () => {
       console.log('Your Message');
    } works and .addEventListener('click', console.log('Your Message')); doesn't?

Comment: ``addEventListener()`` takes 2 mandatory arguments - first is event name and second is handler function in which you tell what to do when that event occurs...

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-addeventlistener-with-examples/